# Mirror multiple physical drives to one partitioned drive in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, partitioning, raid-1, mirroring

Using 'Disk Management' in Windows 10 - can I clone three physical 1tb drives to *one* physical 3tb drive, partitioned into 1tb partitions; i.e. a 1tb partition, mirrors one physical 1tb drive
(...realizing that if the *one* backup drive fails, all of the individual drive's data are no longer protected)?

Comment: What is your question? The idea of RAID-1, software or hardware is that when a drive fails, the others still take over, but you get an error so you know you have to replace the drive.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm aware of and desire.  Though usually - _and possibly the only way, hence my question_ - via two physical drives of the same size; 'not one physical and a partition as queried'.  Fundamentally, that is the question - whether it is possible to mirror to a partition?  Hope that makes sense and thanks for the reply.

Comment: It doesn't, really... Software raid works as follows: you change the type of the drive to dynamic, then create one or more partitions. You select mirroring, and create partitions on various drives. They are shown as one partition, but span multiple drives, and has only one drive letter. In theory, you could have just one drive, create a few small mirror partitions, but that would be a waste of space without any gain.

Comment: Yeah, not sure we're on the same page, yet. So as an example - using Disk Management, after Right-clicking a 1tb drive with data already on it and selecting 'Add Mirror', can I choose a 'Partition' [1 of 3 residing on a separate 3tb drive at 1tb each] to act as a duplicate? Please note: I'm referring to 4 physical drives, three at 1tb each, and one 3tb drive split into 3 partitions to mirror each of the 1tb drives.